# Flutter: Stack ignores Image's alignment property

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a grid of images and I want an delete icon on the top-right position of each image.

I used this code to achieve it:

```
return Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.topRight,
  fit: StackFit.expand,
  children: <Widget>[
    Image(
      image: image,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
    Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.white,),
  ],
);
```

What I got:

[image: stack problem]

The problem is, as you can see, the delete icon is on the center of the image not the up-right even though I set Stack's alignment to `Alignment.topRight`. I know this happens because I set Stack's fit to `StackFit.expand` but if I remove it then Image's fit property will be ignored and I'll get this:

[image: stack problem]

So what should I do if I want to keep my Images square and be able to move the Icon to borders?

Comment: Wrap your `Icon` in `Positioned` and set `right: 0`, `top: 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the alignment only for the icon, so wrap the icon in an `Align` widget and set its alignment.

```
return Stack(
  fit: StackFit.expand,
  children: <Widget>[
    Image(
      image: image,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
      child: Icon(
        Icons.delete,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```